# Размер структуры различается у разных компиляторах

Tags: c++, qt, struct

Вот небольшая программка.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
union ArincMsg {
    uint32_t v;
    char array[4];
    struct {
        char address        : 8;
        int data            : 23;
        char bitParity      : 1;
    } f;
};
int main()
{
    ArincMsg msg;
    cout<< sizeof(msg) << endl;
    msg.f.address = 6;
    msg.f.data = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << int(msg.array[i]) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

На сайте: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler, выдает:

```
4
6 1 0 0
```

А программа Qt (компилятор **MinGW 5.3.0 32bit for C++**) выдает:

```
12
6 0 0 0
```

Почему так и как исправить?

OC Windows 10.
[image: Параметры сборки]

Comment: Приведите компилятор и его параметры, использованные во втором случае.

Comment: Вообще-то стоило бы привести версию компилятора и его параметры, а так это не особо чего проясняет.

Comment: Теперь последний шаг: привести параметры, использованные при сборке.

Comment: Это параметры qmake.

Comment: Вообще-то при сборке qmake будет вызывать moc, mingw  и прочее со вполне конкретными параметрами.

Comment: @VTT подскажи как посмотреть

Comment: А там в логе сборки они разве не пишутся? Можно попробовать добавить опцию `-d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указанный в программе паттерн очень популярен в си мире. И там он даже работает (почти всегда), если правильно посчитать все битики.

В с++ подобный код не будет работать - компилятор имеет право вставлять "паддинги" - пропуски.

> 9.6 Bit-fields
>
> The value of the integral constant expression may be larger than the
>   number of bits in the object representation (3.9) of the bit-field’s
>   type; in such cases **the extra bits are used as padding bits** and do not
>   participate in the value representation (3.9) of the bit-field.
>   **Allocation of bit-fields within a class** object is
>   **implementation-defined**. Alignment of bit-fields is
>   implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed into some addressable
>   allocation unit. [ Note: Bit-fields straddle allocation units on some
>   machines and not on others. Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on
>   some machines, left-to-right on others. —end note ]

Можно попытаться конечно использовать директивы для упаковки структуры, но... не стоит.

Что же делать? переходить на си или писать "парсинг" ручками.

Answer (score 3):

В экземпляре `union` в один момент времени может быть активным только одно поле (за исключением общих блоков классов standard layout). Соответственно обращение к `msg.array` после инициализации `msg.f` является неопределенным поведением.

> **12.3 Unions [class.union]**
>
> 1 In a union, a non-static data member is active if its name refers to an object whose lifetime has begun and has not ended (6.8). At most one of the non-static data members of an object of union type can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.
>
> Example:

```
struct X { const int a; int b; };
union Y { X x; int k; };
void g() {
Y y = { { 1, 2 } }; // OK, y.x is active union member (12.2)
int n = y.x.a;
y.k = 4; // OK: ends lifetime of y.x, y.k is active member of union
y.x.b = n; // undefined behavior: y.x.b modified outside its lifetime,
           // S(y.x.b) is empty because X’s default constructor is deleted,
           // so union member y.x’s lifetime does not implicitly start
}
```

> 6 [Note: In general, one must use explicit destructor calls and placement new-expression to change the active member of a union. —end note ]

Пример, как это обойти:

```
struct t_Fields
{
    char address  : 8;
    int data      : 23;
    char bitParity: 1;
};

t_Fields f{};
f.address = 6;
f.data = 1;
f.bitParity = 0;

// обращение к байтовому представлению
char const * const p_bytes{reinterpret_cast<char const *>(::std::addressof(f))};
for (::std::size_t i{}; i < sizeof(f); ++i)
{
    cout << int{p_bytes[i]} << " ";
}

// обращение к интовому представлению
::std::uint32_t v{};
static_assert(sizeof(f) == sizeof(v));
::std::memcpy
(
   static_cast<void *>(::std::addressof(v))
,  static_cast<void const *>(::std::addressof(f))
,  sizeof(v)
);
cout << v << " ";
```

Comment: я не понимаю что тут написано. Что значит активным поле? Что за общие поля?

Comment: @KtoTo Ну вот у вас в `union` три поля `v`, `array` и `f`. После инициализации `msg.f.address = 6;` поле `f` становится активным, а получение значения хранящегося в `array` приводит к неопределенному поведению. Так что этот код работать не будет. Общие поля могут быть у классов со `standard layout`, которых в данном примере нет, но для которых сделано исключение.

Comment: так `union` разве не придуман для того что бы при изменении одного поля, изменялись другие поля, которые находятся там же?

Comment: @KtoTo Внезапно нет, такое его использование является обычной ошибкой (хотя С в этом плане более разнузданный). Ровно как и использование для таких целей `reinterpret_cast` (который позволяет получать доступ к байтовому представлению данных, но не наоборот). Механизм для корректного использования оверлеев в язык скопировать из ады не удосужились.

Comment: и опять ничего не понял, кроме того что это является ошибкой. @VTT не говоришь как правильно делать. И не приводишь пример почему это не правильно.

Comment: @KtoTo Добавил пример.

Comment: @KtoTo, это неправильно потому, что язык запрещает так делать. Правильно читать из union только то, что туда было до этого записано. Всё остальное — неправильно.

Comment: Ещё раз тут напишу - структура t_Fields не объязательно будет 4 байта. Поэтому эти все игры с кастами до добра не доведут.

Comment: @KoVadim Это учитывается в коде. Основная проблема в том, что даже если поле будет 4 байта, то читать данные из других полей `union` все равно будет нельзя.

Comment: static_assert это конечно хорошо, но вот на студийно  попробовал - а там не выполняется... И как написано в стандарте, порядок выделения места под битовые поля может быть как справа на лево, так и слева на право...

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, за пояснение. Могу ли как альтернативу `union` использовать `varian`?

Comment: в смысле std::variant? учитывая, что он скорее всего также построен на union - нет. Да, это очень печально, что в с++ так интересно впилили это все, но... что поделать. Пишите свой язык

Comment: @KtoTo `::std::variant` при попытке обращения к неактивному полю кидает исключение `std::bad_variant_access`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать структуру:

```
union ArincMsg {
    uint32_t v;
    char array[4];
    struct {
        uint32_t address        : 8;
        uint32_t data           : 23;
        uint32_t bitParity      : 1;
    } f;
};
```

И тогда все будет работать ожидаемо. Видимо проблема в выравнивании переменных (спасибо @KoVadim).

Comment: тут размер структуры `4`, а выводит `6 1 0 0`

Comment: Игры с особенностями реализации до добра не доводят. Сегодня работает, а завтра может и перестать.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь попробовать данный атрибут структуре

```
__attribute__((packed))
```

Убирает выравнивание